# F# type visibility issue

Tags: f#

I declare several types in a separated files, but when I try to use some one from another one, I found some types are not visible for another.
For example, I declare type `Rule` (namespace UGP.Core):
[image: type Rule]
and then I tried to use it in another type declaration (with the same namespace):
[image]
links to large images:

- http://take.ms/MqXrL
- http://take.ms/9OjyZ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

F# projects work differently than C# or VB.NET projects. The *order* of the files in the project is important. Files are compiled sequentially and classes cannot be used until after they have been declared.

Try moving Rule.fs above Grammar.fs by right-clicking on Rule.fs and selecting <kbd>Move Up</kbd>:
[image: Menu]

Comment: This is a great answer. I'd upvote it if it was on the 57 dups of this question :(